# Mysql syntax error running total

Tags: mysql, sql

The Employee table holds the salary information in a year.

Write a SQL to get the cumulative sum of an employee's salary over a period of 3 months but exclude the most recent month.

The result should be displayed by 'Id' ascending, and then by 'Month' descending.

Example
Input

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 1  | 2     | 30     |
| 2  | 2     | 30     |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
| 1  | 3     | 40     |
| 3  | 3     | 60     |
| 1  | 4     | 60     |
| 3  | 4     | 70     |
```

Output

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 3     | 90     |
| 1  | 2     | 50     |
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 3  | 3     | 100    |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
```

Explanation
Employee '1' has 3 salary records for the following 3 months except the most recent month '4': salary 40 for month '3', 30 for month '2' and 20 for month '1'
So the cumulative sum of salary of this employee over 3 months is 90(40+30+20), 50(30+20) and 20 respectively.

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 3     | 90     |
| 1  | 2     | 50     |
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
```

Employee '2' only has one salary record (month '1') except its most recent month '2'.

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
```

Employ '3' has two salary records except its most recent pay month '4': month '3' with 60 and month '2' with 40. So the cumulative salary is as following.

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 3  | 3     | 100    |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
```

My query is

```
SELECT e.id, e.month,
       RunningTotal = sum(e.salary ) OVER (ORDER BY e.Id  ,e.month ) 
FROM employee e inner join
     employee e2
      on e.id=e2.id and e.month=e2.month and
         e.month <> (select max(month) from employee group by id having id=e.id )
order by e.id asc, e.month desc
```

Error I am getting is

> Line 3: SyntaxError: near '(ORDER BY e.Id  ,e.month )  FROM employee e
>   inner join  employee e2 on e.id=e2.i'

Comment: MySQL only supports window functions since version 8.  That is probably the issue with your query.

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask another qestion and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: any idea how this can be transformed to run in mysql

Comment: you need to provide structure of your tables to let us help you

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query:

```
select id, month, salary,
       (select sum(salary) from tbl where id = t.id and month <= t.month) cumulative
from tbl t
where month <> (select max(month) from tbl where id = t.id)
order by id, month desc
```

Comment: @Nayyar if my answer solved your problem you should accept it and optionally upvote.